# If there is an answer posted in the comments - can I still answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

If someone posts the answer to a particular question (or the idea of the solution) in a comment, but has not posted this as an answer - can I post an answer using the same solution?

In particular, here are 2 cases:

1) I finished writing an answer and am ready to post it - only to realize that in the meantime someone else suggested the same thing in a comment 'x' minutes ago. (Maybe it depends on 'x'?)

2) The comment was written a long time ago - x hours/days etc - this time I saw the comment before writing an answer.

Comment: I would attribute the author in my post if the question/comment is old (as in months/years)

Answer (score 4):

Comments shouldn't be used to answer the question, so converting the comment that should be answer to answer is a good thing.

However, do it only when the comment author doesn't want to do it for some reason. First add comment with @author and write you think, his comment should be posted as an answer. If he/she doesn't respond in reasonable time, do it yourself.

Comment: This has happened earlier and seeing this comment someone else posts the exact same thing and upvotes pour-in.. While all those should  be gone to the original one who posted the comment..

Comment: @RoyMJ In all fairness by posting an answer as a comment people are giving permission for others to take that comment and (probably expand it to) post it as a full answer. If people want to answer they should answer

Comment: @RichardTingle : Hmm.. Agree to this...

Comment: In the first case if a comment is added while I am posting an answer I will answer the question anyway. In the second case I will ask the commentator to add it as an answer if he don't I will add my answer (probably as CW if required).